# Windows 7 phone Web development issues

Tags: html, css, windows-phone-7, media-queries

I've developed a website which uses media queries to support mobile devices but Windows Mobile 7 doesn't seem to be affected. I know IE doesn't support media queries so I guess it's the same on WinMob. Is there any way to load a different page on this phone??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just get the [user agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4372397/how-to-get-a-windows-phone-7s-useragent-string/4373781#4373781) and check if it is Windows Phone 7 (this is the samsung focus):

```
Mozilla/4.0 (compatible: MSIE 7.0; Windows Phone OS 7.0; Trident/3.1; IEMobile/7.0; SAMSUNG; SGH-i917)
```

Then redirect to another page.

Comment: Ah OK Thanks. I guess I can load my media query based css file then too. Will try tomorrow!

Comment: That's a great way. I've also found it a much better way of finding if the browser is IE rather than the seemingly buggy <!--[If IE]-->!

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```
<!--[IEMobile]>  
<meta name="MobileOptimized" content="width" /> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ie-mobile.css"/>
<![endif]-->
```

But even better would be setting up for mobile-first, see the absence of Media Queries as a Media Query so to speak. And use:

```
<!--[if (lte IE 8)&!(IEMobile)]>   <html lang="en" class="ieLte8"> <![endif]-->
```

So that you can use the selector: .ieLte8 to do the same as you would for medium displays via Media Queries.

Comment: I've found the whole if statements pickup by IE in the <!--[]--> to not be consistent and picking up the user agent in php is a lot more reliable!!

Comment: True. Using if IE only seemed to work sometimes for me. Can't remember what version of IE I was using but it wasn't very consistent.